# Given a Hamiltonian of a Spin System, How to check it is complete and also conserved?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-spin, hamiltonian-formalism, open-quantum-systems

Hi I am an engineering student trying some modelling in physics. Suppose you have a Hamiltonian of a spin system interacting with another two-level spin system as below. How do you know all the terms are included in the Hamiltonian (true Hamiltonian) and it is conserved.

If I am to do a Lagrange test , any tips on how to convert this to a Lagrangian.

Appreciate any direction/advice to work on.

[image: Suppose you have a Hamiltonian as below. How do you know it's a complete Hamiltonian]